# CMake Error - No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found. For a particular project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to compile a cmake base OpenGL project, which perfectly compiles on my MacBook on a windows environment. When run on windows it throws me this error

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
```

At first I though it might be because of some missing libraries on my system but when I tried another project from [here](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl) following the instructions given [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/), I was successfully able to compile it and generate a VS solution. Cant seem to understand what I am missing

here is my`CmakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(GLParticles)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(GLParticles main.cpp ParticleWorld.cpp ParticleWorld.h)

include_directories(GLTestBed/ext/glew-2.1.0/include)
include_directories(GLTestBed/ext/SFML-2.4.2/include)

include_directories(GLTestBed/src)
include_directories(GLTestBed/ext/glm)


target_link_libraries(GLParticles GlTestBed)

if(APPLE)
  include_directories(/usr/local/include)

  target_link_libraries(GLParticles GlTestBed
    /usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0/lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib
    /usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.4.2_1/lib/libsfml-window.2.4.2.dylib
    /usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.4.2_1/lib/libsfml-system.2.4.2.dylib)

  SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-framework OpenGL")
endif()

add_subdirectory(GLTestBed)
```

Comment: Follow the same instructions as you build the other project, but build your project instead.

Comment: did exactly that only when i got the error

Comment: Did you try running cmake-gui from a Visual Studio command prompt (one with the environment setup up for the compiler).

Comment: Please try deleting the generated CMakeCache.txt and try again.

Comment: @drescherjm that was indeed the case, weird though as I didn't need to do that to compile the other program. was wondering if there is some path/setting we can set in CmakeLists so that it will work from any command prompt ?

Comment: I just use the VS command prompt every time. In addition in my case I have a shortcut that launches the VS command prompt with additional environment variables set for my other software. I have several such shortcuts depending on the build tree.